# Show, if $P(A|C_i) \geq P(B|C_i)$ then $P(A) \geq P(B)$. Is my idea right?

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C_1,\dots,C_n$ be events on a discrete probability space $(\Omega,P)$.

Where $P(C_i) > 0, P(A|C_i) \geq P(B|C_i)$ for all $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} C_i = \Omega$.

**Task 1:**
Show that $P(A) \geq P(B)$, if the events $C_1,\dots ,C_n$ are disjoint.

**Task 2:** What if they are not disjoint? Give a counterexample.

**My thoughts on task 1:**

1. After the law of total probability it holds:
   $$P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A|C_i)\cdot P(C_i) $$
   $$P(B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(B|C_i)\cdot P(C_i) $$
2. So if 
   $$P(A|C_i) \geq P(B|C_i)$$ 
   then it should also hold that
   $$P(A|C_i)\cdot P(C_i) \geq P(B|C_i)\cdot P(C_i)$$
   because I multiply with the same value.
3. because of 2. it should also hold that:
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A|C_i)\cdot P(C_i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(B|C_i)\cdot P(C_i) $$
4. And because of 1.) 2.) and 3.) my final conclusion would be:
   $$P(A) \geq P(B)$$

Is that correct?

For task 2 i have no idea yet^^

kind regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task 2: Let
$$\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\text{ (uniform distribution)}$$
$$A=\{1,2,3\}$$
$$B_1=\{4,5\}$$
$$B_2=\{6,7\}$$
$$B=B_1\cup B_2=\{4,5,6,7\}$$
$$C_1=A\cup B_1=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$C_2=A\cup B_2=\{1,2,3,6,7\}.$$
Then $C_1\cup C_2=\Omega$ and, for $i\in\{1,2\}$ we have
$$P(A|C_i)=\frac35\gt\frac25=P(B|C_i),$$
while
$$P(A)=\frac37\lt\frac47=P(B).$$